# Fancybox returning " The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later."

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, fancybox

Using [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) to [play youtube videos in a modal box](http://chadly.net/post/2009/01/29/Lightbox-for-YouTube-Videos.aspx).

My Problem is that I keep getting "The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later."

The modal box is popping up so I know the script is running, it might be a problem with my API call... here is my call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

            /* This is basic - uses default settings */

            $("a.fancybox").fancybox({
                'hideOnContentClick': true
            });

            /* This is a non-obtrustive method for youtube videos*/

            $("a[rel=fancyvideo]").fancybox({
                overlayShow: true,
                frameWidth:640,
                frameHeight:360,
            });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you have any `<a>`s with both `class="fancybox"` and `rel="fancyvideo"`? If you do then you'll be binding Fancybox to those elements twice and Fancybox might not like that. Try taking out this one:

```
$("a.fancybox").fancybox({
    'hideOnContentClick': true
});
```

And see what happens with just the second one in place.

**UPDATE**: Strange. The demo (http://chadly.net/demos/video-lightbox.html) is producing different HTML than your page, the demo builds an `<object data=...>` but yours builds a `<object><embed src="youtube-url">` thing. You're saying:

```
type: 'swf'
```

in your Fancybox binding, that's where the `<object><embed>...</embed></object>` stuff comes from. However, the `href` points at a plain old YouTube video viewing HTML page and that `href` ends up as the `src` attribute for the `<embed>`. The URL for embedding a YouTube video isn't the same as the video's HTML page and that's probably the source of your problem.

Try replacing the `href` that looks like this:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QmVvgSfdmJQ
```

with one like this:

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/QmVvgSfdmJQ
```

The first is the plain HTML page for YouTube, the second is the embeddable SWF.

**UPDATE 2**: The example you're working from is for Fancybox 1.0.0 but you're using 1.3.4, 1.0.0 has some special checks for YouTube that aren't present in later versions:

```
//...
} else if (url.match(/youtube\.com\/watch/i)) {
//...
```

That's from 1.0.0 and the code after that `else if` rewrites the HTML page URL (e.g. `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QmVvgSfdmJQ`) to the older embeddable SWF URL (e.g. `http://www.youtube.com/v/QmVvgSfdmJQ`). This version problem also explains why the demo was producing different HTML than your's.

So, you have some version problems on top of everything else.

Comment: Good call, unfortunately, I already tried that. No dice.  I am not using the same class on the rel to youtube video.  Also removed the first Fancybox call and it doesn't change anything.  You can see the site here: http://anasmadance.com.s66112.gridserver.com/about/repertoire/ ... click on the first large title div to expand it and then look for "watch the video"

Comment: @Brian: I mucked around a bit and added an update that may (or may not) be of use.

Comment: @Brain: But wait! There's even more fun and version issues to boot. Check my second update if you're curious, no wonder there was confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have included the **jquery.fancybox-media.js**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.0"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your code might be slightly off

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a[@rel*=fancyvideo]").fancybox({
            overlayShow: true,
            frameWidth:640,
            frameHeight:360
        });
    });
</script>
```

http://chadly.net/post/2009/01/29/Lightbox-for-YouTube-Videos.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately no, the author posted this before jQuery 1.3.2 and so the code in his post is wrong.  Before updating it, the code didn't work at all, afterward I got the modal box to appear but no video.

Answer (score 1):

use this sample don't forget href

```
<a class="fancybox" href="your path for image or other">
  <img src="imagepath">
</a>
```