# fancybox automatically on document ready

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have a fancybox to load every time that I load a page.
But when the fancybox open give me this error:

> The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later.

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#inline1").fancybox().trigger('click');
    });
</script>

<div id="inline1" style="display:none;">
    <p>
    Some text
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: MAy Be this old question can help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913583/fancybox-returning-the-requested-content-cannot-be-loaded-please-try-again-lat

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941002/fancybox-returning-the-requested-content-cannot-be-loaded-please-try-again-la

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857849/fancybox-the-requested-content-cannot-be-loaded-please-try-again-later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using fancybox **v1.3.4** (most likely) then you need to wrap your `inline` content in a hidden `div`; in other words, the `inline` (targeted) content shouldn't have the property `display: none` but the parent wrapper.

So the correct structure should be

```
<div style="display:none;">
  <div id="inline1">
    <p> Some text </p>
  </div>
</div>
```